# Kivy, screenmanager, sqlite. Screen does not update as I switch to new screen

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy, clock

The function of this code should be that you enter a value and press "Add." and it saves the data to the sqlite database and switch to "Next" screen. This screen should show the list of values added but...
I cant make it update from database (including the new "add") as you switch screen.
Then I tried to make a "Update" button. This works but its so annoying that it does not update as I switch screen.
I tried with "Clock.schedule_interval" and several other foolish escapades.
I really hope you can help me out on this one

The code is in three parts. test.py, kvtest.kv and db_test.py

- test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import db_test

db_test.sq_crea()

print(db_test.sq_crea())


class Main(Screen):
    inp = ObjectProperty(None)
    attempt = 1

    def btn(self):
        self.attempt = self.attempt + 1

        inp = self.inp.text
        db_test.insert_data(inp)
        self.inp.text = f"Attempt {self.attempt}"

        print(inp)


class Next(Screen):

    def out1(self):
        updtdb = self.reset_text()
        self.ids.out1.text = updtdb
        return self.ids.out1.text

    def reset_text(self):
        updtdb = str(db_test.data_out())
        return updtdb

    def up(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.reset_text, 1)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


gui = Builder.load_file("kvtest.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        access_to_next_class = Next()
        access_to_next_class.out1()
        return gui


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

- kvtest.kv

```
WindowManager:
    Main:
    Next:

<Label>
    font_size : 0.08*self.width
    color: 1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1

<Button>
    font_size : 0.08*self.width
    color: 1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1

<TextInput>
    font_size : 0.08*self.width
    color: 1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1

<Main>
    name: "main"
    inp : inp

    FloatLayout:
        cols:2
        Button:
            text: 'Add to database'
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "bottom": 1}
            on_release:
                root.btn()
                app.root.current = "next"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        TextInput:
            id:inp
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "bottom": 0.8}
            text: 'Attempt 1'

<Next>
    name: "next"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "bottom": 0.8}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

        Button:
            id: upd
            text: "Update"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "bottom": 0.8}
            on_release:
                root.out1()

        Label:
            id: out1
            text: root.out1()
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.5}
```

- db_test.py

```
import sqlite3

def sq_crea():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("db_test.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_test(        
        info text NOT NULL     
        )''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return 'Connected to db_test.db'




def insert_data(inp):
    with sqlite3.connect("db_test.db") as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO db_test(info) VALUES(?)",
                  (inp,))
        conn.commit()


def data_out():
    with sqlite3.connect("db_test.db") as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM db_test")
        conn.commit()
        items = c.fetchall()
        i = 0
        out_list = ""
        for item in items:
            string = items[i][0]
            out_list = f"{out_list} \n {string}"
            i += 1
        return out_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on_enter()` method of `Screen`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen). For example:

```
class Next(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.out1()
```